# Add column to dynamically generated table? Or have content dynamically generated from second column of row?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic "availability" schedular. I show one week at a time, defaults to the current week, with buttons to move back and forth, while the first column will show resources (names, rooms etc). I am new-ish to Javascript. I was able to populate the calendar dates starting with the current week, and now have the Previous/Next buttons working. But I can't quite figure out how to add a column.
Here is what I currently have:
[image: Dynamically generated row, shows one week at a time]

Here's kind of what I'm aiming for:
[image: Dynamically add column of names]

A link to the current code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/surista/h0uvsdpz/1/

I've tried to dynamically add a column to this, but can't seem to get it. I then tried to add the column in the HTML and then have the dates auto-populate from the -second- column, but this hasn't worked either.

This is my current Javascript code:

```
function showDays(startDay){
  let start = moment(startDay);
  window.SelectedSunday = start; // save it for future use

  let table = document.getElementById("calendar");
  tbl_body = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

  // display month and year in table header
  let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
  monthAndYear.innerHTML = start.format('MMM YYYY');

  // always only show one row
  if (table.rows.length == 2) {
    table.deleteRow(1);
  }

  let row = table.insertRow(1);

  day = start.format('DD'); // Get day
  let cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = day;

  for(let i = 1; i < 7; i++){
    // iterate through days of week
    start.add(1, 'days');
    day = start.format('DD'); // Get day
    let cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML = day;
  }
}

function nextWeek() {
  window.SelectedSunday.add(1, 'days');
  showDays(window.SelectedSunday);
}

function previousWeek() {
  window.SelectedSunday.add(-13, 'days');
  showDays(window.SelectedSunday);
}

window.SelectedSunday = null;
let currentSunday = moment().startOf('week');

showDays(currentSunday);
```

Answer (score 0):

VanillaJS solution to 'add' columns, add rows and navigate through weeks.

```js
"use strict";

const calendarDate = new Date();
const dow = calendarDate.getDay();
const today = calendarDate.getDate();
calendarDate.setDate(today - dow);

function labelHeaders() {
  // set month header
  const options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long'
  };
  document.getElementById("month").textContent = calendarDate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);

  // get all the <th>s for the days
  const dayHeader = document.querySelectorAll("#dateNumbers th:nth-child(1n+2)");

  // loop through the <th>s and put the dates
  let day = 0;
  while (day < 7) {
    dayHeader[day].textContent = calendarDate.getDate();
    calendarDate.setDate(calendarDate.getDate() + 1);
    day++;
  }
}

labelHeaders();

document.getElementById("goButtons").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  // next doesn't do anything but call labelHeaders because the date is advancing contiguously

  if (evt.target.id === "prev") {
    // backup 14 days
    const currentCalendarDate = calendarDate.getDate();
    calendarDate.setDate(currentCalendarDate - 14);
  }

  // update headers
  labelHeaders();
});

document.getElementById("showButtons").addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  // use the id to get the target id of the row to reveal
  const id = evt.target.id.replace('show', '').toLowerCase();
  // show the heading for the column, since all these buttons add rows
  document.querySelectorAll("#calendar th:first-child").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("hidden"));
  // add a new row or show an existing row
  if (id === "makenewrow") {
    const newRow = document.getElementById("newRow").content.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("calendar-body").appendChild(newRow);
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.table-bordered td,
.table-bordered th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="month"></h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hidden"></th>
      <th>Sun</th>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
      <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="dateNumbers">
      <th class="hidden">Name</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="calendar-body">
    <tr id="harry" class="hidden">
      <th scope="row">Harry</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ron" class="hidden">
      <th scope="row">Ron</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="hermione" class="hidden">
      <th scope="row">Hermione</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="showButtons">
  <button id="showHarry">Show Harry</button>
  <button id="showRon">Show Ron</button>
  <button id="showHermione">Show Hermione</button>
  <button id="makeNewRow">Make new row</button>
</div>
<div id="goButtons">
  <button id="prev">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>

<template id="newRow">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">New</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm, close, but this has the dates (1, 2, 3 etc. above) hard-coded - actually the dates are generated dynamically, and can change (previous/next buttons will shift the dates back/forth one week).

The idea is that the first column will stay static, with the other columns -except- the days of the week moving back/forth.

Comment: Updated code 